# Why does this bike have bosses on the bottom of the down tube?

Tags: frames

What can the bosses on the down tube, next to the front wheel, be used for? The only thing I can think of is a mountain bike style mudguard, but I've only seen ones that clip on.

[Evans' Cycles website](https://www.evanscycles.com/pinnacle-arkose-3-2017-adventure-road-bike-EV275624).

Click to zoom in:
[image: https://static.evanscycles.com/production/bikes/cyclocross-bikes/product-image/Original/pinnacle-arkose-3-2017-adventure-road-bike-matt-orange-black-EV275624-2000-1.jpg]

[image: https://static.evanscycles.com/production/bikes/cyclocross-bikes/product-image/Original/pinnacle-arkose-3-2017-adventure-road-bike-matt-orange-black-EV275624-2000-2.jpg]

Comment: My first thought was "third waterbottle cage"  but there's no way it would fit there.

Comment: There are varieties of mudguards, like [this one](http://www.jonesbikes.com/crud-catcher-front/), which would use those bosses. When you have under downtube bottle cages, they're further back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are most likely bosses for a "Crud Catcher", a type of mudguard usually clipped to the downtube. Some frames allow them to be bolted to it rather than fastened on with rubber o-rings.

Answer (score 10):

I would have to assume those are the...

> Extra Features:
>   Tyre clearance for up to 700 x 45c with full mudguard and rack mounts

...that are mentioned on their website. Too far apart and to close to the tire to be anything else really.

Comment: I'm not sure about "full mudguard... mounts" referring to bosses on the downtube.  I think that refers to the hole in the fork crown and the threaded hole at the bottom of each fork.  "Full" preceding "mudguard"   in reference to something like the front crudcatcher that Batman linked is deceptive too

Comment: It is deceptive, and i would guess its more marketing than literal. A lot of pump mounts use the same bolt spacing as water bottle cages so that also seemed unlikely to me. Perhaps the word full is in reference to having a full array of options, for either the type Batman specified or a standard "full" fender.

Answer (score 0):

That's where I put my pump, so maybe they're for a pump. It looks like a road morph like I've got or an old fashioned pump would fit there. Most pump brackets will fit bottle cage screws or clamp on directly to the frame so it seems a bit unnecessary.

I was right next to one of these bikes on the train yesterday and there's quite a bit of clearance there.

Comment: Maybe - but from the photos the underside mounts look further apart than the drink bottle cage ones.